# Python Sub-Process Coverage

Tags: python-2.7, code-coverage, pyc

**Situation:**
I'm attempting to get coverage reports for a project that uses both C++ and Python. I'm using LCOV/GCOV for C++, and attempting to use [Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/) for the python stuff. The only issue is, most of the python code that's being used is simply utility functions being called one function at a time. No initialization, no real life-cycle, or exit. So no real way to use the API to start/stop/save, or use the coverage command line to measure.

With this, I thought the easiest way to accomplish this would be using the sitecustomize.py method like outlined [here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/subprocess.html). I have gotten that to work, and it measures all configured python code as expected. ***Now I'm looking at how to accomplish this with compiled python code*** (.pyc).

I can get it to work if I keep source(.py) and (.pyc) in the same directory when running, and then reporting. However, I'm looking for a way to RUN the files and generate the measurement data. Then at a later time point to the actual source files, and run the actual reports. Ideally I wouldn't need the source(.py) files at all, but I haven't found a way to accomplish this.

***Objective:***
In the end I want to be able to compile the python files(.pyc), install them on the target, and run coverage like stated above. It will generate coverage data files, then pull those files to my host machine which houses the source(.py) .. and do the actual coverage reporting.

Is this possible currently?

[Edit] Thanks to Ned's advice, I looked into the [paths] usage, and it worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: Help me understand: why is it important to measure coverage without the source files present?  And what goes wrong now when the source files are not present?

Comment: All existing calls are to pyc files, so have to keep that. I could simply copy both files to target, but figured/hoped there may be a cleaner way. Without them it simply outputs a blank report.

Comment: You should be able to run coverage on the .pyc files, and then produce the report where the sources are. Copy the .coverage file back to a place where the sources are first.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. It appears the .coverage files reference the absolute path of the file it's measuring. For instance when I run my app from /usr/local/ it seems to want to look for the source in /usr/local/. If that's truly the case, seems like there could be a switch added to strip those absolutes out, or even to provide a new "source_root" directory to run reports against.

Comment: @NedBatchelder do you know if Coverage.py and the sitecustomize.py method will measure what amount to static python calls from C++ via methods like PyImport_ImportModule??

Comment: About the paths: read about the `[paths]` setting for "coverage combine". About the C++-called code: coverage.py will measure Python execution, even if it's because the module was loaded by C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I will take a look and see what I've missed with the combine command.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yes, as expected the [paths] was something I had overlooked, and did exactly what I needed. Thank you. I have generated a second regarding the C++/Python callback coverage to avoid confusion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150922/python-coverage-for-c-pyimport).